# google maps api v3 infowindow + flot

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, flot, infowindow

I'm trying to draw a graph inside an `infowindow`, but flot is not executing—and is not throwing any errors. I read in the flot forum that often people have trouble with doing something like this because the placeholder element must be visible (that might be a red-herring here tho).

I'm able to get the following to produce the graph appropriately in a different element:

```
$.plot(
    $("#placeholder"),
    [ f_data[loc] ],
    {
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        series: {
           bars: { show: true },
           clickable:true,
           color:'#3FA9F5',
           shadowSize: 0
       },//series
       xaxis: {
           tickDecimals:0,
           tickSize:1
       }//xaxis
    }
);//$.plot
```

But when I put the above into, or referenced from, the `google.maps.event.addListener()`, it does nothing (not even add the `<canvas>` elements).

I made sure to put it after `infowindow.open(map,marker);`, so that makes me think the placeholder element is visible. I also made sure `#placeholder` has substance/defined dimensions.

P.S. I tried what Mike Williamson reported as his eventual solution to [Google Maps V3: Loading infowindow content via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381700/), but that didn't work either.

**EDIT**
Example of flot working outside of infowindow: [index2.html](http://clients.frende.me/incognito/index2.html)
Example of flot not working inside of infowindow (addListener 'domready'): [index3.html](http://clients.frende.me/incognito/index3.html)
Example of flot not working inside of infowindow (setTimeout): [index4.html](http://clients.frende.me/incognito/index4.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the content div has not been attached to the domain yet (so $("#placeholer") can't find it).  You need to wait for the infowindow domready event to fire before running your code to plot the graph, something like this:

UPDATE:  The code below works for me on a local copy (I did modify the css, but I don't think that was required).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, locale, s, flot_data) {
  return function() {
    var fname = 'http://clients.frende.me/incognito/images/'+date+'_'+locale.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'')+'.svg';
    infowindow.setContent('<div id="gMaps_infowindow"><h3>'+locale+' ('+hour+':00): $'+s.total+'</h3><div id="flotIW" style="height:200px; width:350px;" name="'+locale+'"></div></div>');

  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {(function(f_data,loc) {
    $.plot(
      $("#flotIW"),
      [ f_data[loc] ],
      {
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        series: {
          bars: { show: true },
          clickable:true,
          color:'#3FA9F5',
          shadowSize: 0
        },//series
      xaxis: {
        tickDecimals:0,
        tickSize:1
      }//xaxis
    }
  );//$.plot
  })(flot_data,locale)});

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    //open_popUp(flot_data,locale);
    //open_drawGraph(locale);
  }//return
})(marker, locale, s, flot_data));//google.maps.event.addListener
```

(another option is to create the domain node directly, use that to render your graph, and pass that into the setContent call (which will take either a string or a DOM node).

Comment: I added `google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', (function(f_data,loc) { … })(flot_data,locale));` after the first addLister and I got an *Invalid dimensions* error from flot.

Comment: Code in comments is difficult to read, but it doesn't look like you included everything.  I don't know anything about flot (just the Google Maps API v3), but that error sounds like the "placeholder" div either doesn't have a size or has a size that flot doesn't like.  Might be time for a live example.

Comment: This suggestion is correct, see a simplified JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Aykg2/ ... You'll notice there are no more setTimeouts used.

Comment: @Ryley do you know why the content is too big for the infowindow in your fiddle? When I tried it before (with the empty `#flot div`), the infowindow grew itself properly.

Comment: @Ryley: I fixed it by moving the `infowindow.open(map, marker);` before the `google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() { … });`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your `$.plot` in a `setTimeout(function(){$.plot({stuff})}, 0)` ?

Sometimes this helps give the browser time to finish drawing whatever elements it needs to before it executes.

You can find more information why this might be useful here: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: Tried this instead: `setTimeout( open_drawGraph(locale) , 0 );` and got a *useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)* error.

Comment: Ah, sorry, setTimeout expects a function object not an invocation (documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).  I've updated my answer to correct this error on my part.

Comment: added live examples to question